# GSM Antenna - SIM800L

Tags: microcontroller, antenna, gsm

I want a 90 degree rotate antenna for my SIM800L module.I couldn't find one so I hooked up a wifi antenna & it worked nicely.Does it matter for reliability?
Does it match with my sim800L module?

My GSM subscriber = 900Mhz-2100Mhz

## Wifi Antenna Spec

This is a true 6dBi antennas
Gain: 6dBi
Radiation: Omni
Connector: RP-SMA
Frequency Range: 2.4 Ghz ~ 5.8 Ghz
Antenna length: extended 6.3 inches (16.1cm) and folded 5.4 inches (13.7cm)
Suitable for wireless LAN and WiFi router adapter
Compatible with all mini PCI card or most mini PCI-E card
Great for wireless router, access point repair or similar projects
Compliant with IEEE 802.11a, 802.11b, 802.11g, 802.11n wireless LANs.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/6dBi-WiFi-RP-SMA-2-4GHz-5GHz-Dual-Band-flat-Antenna-for-TL-WA5110G-USB-Adapter-/392535637250

Comment: The Wi-Fi antenna has 6dBi gain on the 2.4GHz and 5.8GHz bands. On other frequencies it will just have lower gain (even below 0dBi). If you don't plan to use it in remote areas where the GSM signal is low, it is perfectly fine. In cities where the GSM towers are very close, the SIM800L module will decrease the Tx power to the minimum required value, so there will be no issues with impedance mismatch (probably the Wi-Fi antenna doesn't have 50 ohms on GSM bands) and signal reflection back to the module.

Comment: You are very correct.I tried it on workbench (in the city) & its working nicely.But when I place the module in remote areas where the GSM signal levels are low the module cannot settle in network.I should stick with a proper GSM antenna...!!1

Comment: In remote areas the module will increase the Tx power trying to reach the cell tower. In this case if the antenna impedance is not matched there will be reflections back to the module which can lead to increased power demand, overheating or even damage. A GSM antenna is recommended.